# possible to have characters preceding * in FileDialog filter?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a FileDialog whose filter only allows files matching the expression `xyz*.xlsm`; this would allow files like `xyz123.xlsm` and `xyzzat.xlsm` to be selected, but not `xyz123.docx` or `abc123.xlsm`.

I'm using this code:

```
Sub testfd()

Dim fd As FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fd.Filters.Add "xyz*", "xyz*.xlsm", 1
If fd.Show = -1 Then
    Debug.Print fd.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    Debug.Print "xyz"
End If


End Sub
```

However, the `fd.Filters.Add` line generates this run-time error:

```
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

Using the filter `*.xlsm` works normally.

Is it impossible to use `.Filters.Add` the way I've laid out in my code above?  If so, how can I make sure that the user only selects files that start and end with a given character sequence?

Comment: Edit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219834(v=office.11).aspx Use something like .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1 . Maybe the wildcard does not go in between 2 substrings? I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think you can use a wildcard like that: that argument is only intended for specifying extensions.

Comment: If you badly need it, why not create it from scratch? It is slightly time consuming but simple. I remember doing it once...

Comment: @SiddharthRout, you mean creating my own FileDialog GUI from scratch as a UserForm?  That seems like a pretty elaborate project.

Comment: Is it? See the answer that I posted ;)

Comment: I have added a sample file in the answer below so that if you wish, you can further work on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you badly need it, why not create it from scratch? It is slightly time consuming but simple. I remember doing it once... –  Siddharth Rout 39 mins ago

Here is a quick example that I created for you (*took approx 40 mins to create it*).

Create a userform as shown in the image below and then name them as shown.

[image]

**Userform Code**

Paste this code in the user form

```
Option Explicit

Dim justStarted As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "70;60"
        .ListStyle = fmListStylePlain
    End With
    justStarted = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    justStarted = False
    Populate
End Sub

'~~> Manually changing folder
Private Sub InitialPath_Change()
    If InitialPath = "" Or justStarted = True Then Exit Sub
    
    If Dir(InitialPath) <> "" Then
        Populate
    Else
        ListBox1.Clear
        TextBox2.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Listbox Single Click - File Selection
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    If ListBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    If ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1) = "File" Then _
    TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
End Sub

'~~> Listbox Double Click - Folder Open
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If ListBox1.ListIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    If ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1) = "Folder" Then
        If Right(Me.InitialPath, 1) <> "\" Then
            InitialPath = Me.InitialPath & "\" & ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 0) & "\"
        Else
            InitialPath = Me.InitialPath & ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 0) & "\"
        End If
        
        Populate
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Open Button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Len(Trim(TextBox2.Text)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Right(Me.InitialPath, 1) <> "\" Then InitialPath = Me.InitialPath & "\"
    
    If Dir(InitialPath & TextBox2.Text) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "You selected " & InitialPath & TextBox2.Text
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a valid file"
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Exit Button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

'~~> Populate Listbox
Sub Populate()
    Dim sFile As Variant, sFolder As Variant
    Dim sFilter As String
    Dim pos As Long: pos = 0
    
    ListBox1.Clear
       
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(InitialPath)
    
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        With ListBox1
            .AddItem
            .List(pos, 0) = objSubFolder.Name
            .List(pos, 1) = "Folder"
            pos = pos + 1
        End With
    Next objSubFolder
    
    sFilter = Split(Filter, "(")(1)
    sFilter = Split(sFilter, ")")(0)
    Filter = sFilter
    
    sFile = Dir(InitialPath & Trim(sFilter))
    
    While (sFile <> "")
        With ListBox1
            .AddItem
            .List(pos, 0) = sFile
            .List(pos, 1) = "File"
            pos = pos + 1
        End With
        sFile = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

**Module**

From a module you can call it as

```
Sub Sample()
    With MyFileBrowser
        .InitialPath = "C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\"
        .Filter = "My Files,(*ture*.*)"
        .Caption = "Open"
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

[image]

**Disclaimer**:

1. Error Handling Not done.
2. Works with only Single Filters
3. `Filter` textbox is locked for editing

Comment: Impressive!  I'll see if the PM is willing to go for this, or if they need to have the full functionality of a FileDialog (e.g. new folder create, sort on multiple columns, file rename, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you won't need a solution anymore but this may be helpful for other users who, like myself, looked for a solution of this problem.

There is a way to filter files beyond the file type filters. In the following example I want to see only html files in the folder that start with a string contained in "*AccountNr*". 
To achieve this I add the *AccountNr* string plus an asterisk to the *InitialFileName*. 
The folder's path is not changed by this addition in the *InitialFileName*. The selector field in the *FileDialog* window will show the *AccountNr* string with the asterisk.
(The basic code was found in stackoverflow, I modified it for my needs)

```
Private Function GetURL(AccountNr)
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd

        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\xxxed\Downloads\YY\" & AccountNr & "*"
                'set directory (initial file path) & AccountNr

        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        ' Set the title of the dialog box.
        .Title = "Please select the file."

        ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "HTML Files", "*.html" 'This filters files with "AccountNr*.html"
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"     'alternative filter: all types

        ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
        ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
        ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
        If .Show = True Then
            GetURL = .SelectedItems(1)      'This is the file name and path
        Else
            GetURL = ""
        End If
    End With
End Function
```