# Filter file if file name contains a word when using file dialog

Tags: excel, vba, openfiledialog

I would like to filter files when using the file dialog to select files. I would like to exclude any files that contain "Conflicted" in the name. Is this possible?

```
Sub OpenMultipleFiles()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim fileChosen As Integer
Dim basename As String
Dim fso As Variant
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
basename = fso.getBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
fd.InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path ' Set Default Location to the Active Workbook Path
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
fd.Filters.Add "All supported files", "*.xlsm"

fileChosen = fd.Show
If fileChosen = -1 Then

    StartAlgo

    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim FullPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim x As Long
    
    'open each of the files chosen
    For x = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
        FullPath = fd.SelectedItems(x)
        FileName = fso.getFileName(fd.SelectedItems(x))
        CopyContractTbls FullPath, FileName
    Next x

    EndAlgo
Else
    MsgBox "Aborted"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: IMHO, FileDialog.Filters only supports the `*` wildcard. So to answer your question, it is not possible to achieve what you want with `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` Having said that, you can design your own file dialog using a userform where you can exclude the filenames

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will see if a userform is possible. I have found answer that you posted 6 years ago about this same issue

Comment: Ah a [Blast from the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816543/possible-to-have-characters-preceding-in-filedialog-filter) :D I think you upvoted it and hence I could see which post you were refering to. I had forgotten about it completely

Comment: I have managed to create a better version of that filebrowser where you can exclude strings. Need to test it more. Will paste an answer tomorrow to give you a demo